# working with 'list variables' in the shell. how to prefix to all elements in list?

Tags: shell

I have a (hopefully) simple problem that I've been trying to solve without much success.
Consider the following trivial shell script:

list = "A B C"

for i in $scripts
do
  //some logic
done

echo $list

The desired output from the above example is:

> > right-A right-B right-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` and take advantage of its feature of [re-using the format if extra arguments are given](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf):

```
# specifically, do not quote the variable so that 
# the shell can split it into words
printf "right-%s " $list

# the printf command does not emit a newline, so 
# do it here
echo
```

To capture it as a new variable, assuming bash:

```
printf -v prefixed_list "right-%s " $list
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question, but it is not 100% clear. But I would recommend using BASH as a shell.  And here is what I would do to create the output your are asking for.

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST=(A B C)
for VALUE in "${LIST[@]}"
do
  echo 'right-'${VALUE}
done
```

Comment: You have assumed list as an array. So when you do echo $list it will just print single element. What I need is to update the elements in list to have prefixes and when I do echo $list... i should get the stated output.

Comment: list="A B C" echo $list will give output as A B C 
but list =(A B C) echo $list will give output as A as it is declared as array here

Comment: @Ishwar in this case you can use echo -n 'right-'${VALUE} instead